# POSIX extended Regex - contain not X but Y (std::regex c++11)

Tags: c++, regex, c++11, posix-ere

**Question explanation**

I have been trying to write a regex to pass for exactly this format:

```
"bob likes poo - whatever(&T(R)*HP#"
"  \t  \t  bob likes poo - *^RFVOG(IBHUO)B"
```

but fail on:

```
 "//bob likes poo - GV*(GF*("
 "# \t  bob likes poo - OHG(G(*"
 "bob does not like poo G&((HOUIHBO:"
```

They key bit being.

> The line does NOT start with comment characters(# or //), can have
>   blank spaces(space or tab), has to have something followed by
>   delimeter(" - "), followed by whatever.

The corner cases are:

```
1) " \t   //this is still a comment - YGV^FV*"
```

should still fail.

```
2) "   /i_am//_no_/comment - FG&*G*&G"
```

should pass.

**Random reasoning**

well, I have failed. which made me ask if we can specify somehow to contain some character but not others. for example

```
[^abc]
```

just means any character that is not a, b or c. but how would we say not abc but 123? we can't just put

```
[^abc123]
```

because that will exclude them and can't do

```
[^abc]123
```

because that will mean it has to have 123 after some character that is not a,b,c which is total of 4 chars instead of 1 we want. I have no idea if it is even possible. So there are 2 quetsions here in a sense.

my best bet so far is:

```
 "[[:blank:]]*[^[:blank:]]+( - ).*"
```

this makes the format matching correct but does not account for the comments.

**EDIT**

I have found the working solution. It works but it's ugly as hell:

```
 "[[:blank:]]*([^[:blank:]#]([^/].*)?|[^[:blank:]#/].*)( - ).*"
```

if anyone knows how to make it nicer, please tell me.

Comment: Umm, "not abc but must be 123" is same as "must be 123", or `[123]` as regexp... Or do I misunderstand that part of your question?

Comment: Is this what you want [`^[^\/#-]*(?:\/[^\/][^-]*)?-.*`](https://regex101.com/r/yW9xZ9/1)?

Comment: What if you change non-capturing group `(?:...)` to a capturing group `(...)`?

Comment: You can add spaces around `-` if they are essential parts of input string. `egrep` doesn't support non-capturing groups. That's it. I didn't know it at the first place. I think you don't need to escape slashes too. I just did it since they could be meaningful for RegEx engine.

Comment: Why `- eouhfueo` shouldn't be matched?

Comment: **DO NOT** vandalize your posts. They are to be useful to anyone here on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After understanding more things about requirements within comments I came with this RegEx:

```
^[[:blank:]]*(\/([^\/][^-]*|)|([[:blank:]]|^)[^[:blank:]\/#][^-]*) - .*
```

Matches:

[image]

By the way I don't know why really *bob likes p*** !

Comment: If bob likes it then there he goes. Updated regex.

Comment: If you don't use a  start of string anchor `^` in `grep` then match may occur in middle of string which is undesired. I wasn't sure about `"` if it is used as the input wrapper or not so in my proposed RegEx I excluded it and instead used `^`.  I admit that I didn't pay attention to your working solution. I thought differently from beginning and didn't hesitate to type more. Your own solution is much more cleaner and shorter. I never will go with mine if I had seen yours. Feel free to un-accept this answer.